# Plot pin does not point exact place on MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, uigesturerecognizer

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(foundTap:)];
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [self.myMapView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
}

-(void)foundTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:self.myMapView];  
    CLLocationCoordinate2D tapPoint = [self.myMapView convertPoint:point toCoordinateFromView:self.view];
    MKPointAnnotation *point1 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point1.coordinate = tapPoint;
    [self.myMapView addAnnotation:point1];
}
```

I used above code to make pin point on MKMapView when i choose a place in MKMapView it does not point where i exactly touches.It goes little far where i touches.What is wrong with my code?.any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the passed-in object to the `locationInView:` method to `self.view`:

```
-(void)foundTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];  

    CLLocationCoordinate2D tapPoint = [self.myMapView convertPoint:point toCoordinateFromView:self.view];

    MKPointAnnotation *point1 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];

    point1.coordinate = tapPoint;

    [self.myMapView addAnnotation:point1];
}
```

Comment: How do i get longitude and latitude value of choosing location in MKMapView?

Comment: In your case you would do: `tapPoint.latitude` and `tapPoint.longitude` or `point1.coordinate.latitude` and `point1.coordinate.longitude`. See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

I know the other answer is working for you, but I just wanted to show the proper way to use `convertPoint:toCoordinateFromView:`. Instead of passing it the container view, it should be passed the map view that the point is in:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D tapPoint = [self.myMapView convertPoint:point
                                          toCoordinateFromView:self.myMapView];
```

That saves swapping between views. Here's the full method:

```
-(void)foundTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:self.myMapView];  
    CLLocationCoordinate2D tapPoint = [self.myMapView convertPoint:point toCoordinateFromView:self.myMapView];
    MKPointAnnotation *point1 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point1.coordinate = tapPoint;
    [self.myMapView addAnnotation:point1];
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer.How do i get longitude and latitude value of choosing location in MKMapView?

Comment: They are contained in the `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, in the variable `point1` in your code.